# TvOS universal app ad identifier

Tags: ads, tvos, apple-tv

If I want to submit my tvOS build for review do I need to click yes on the "does your app use a advertising identifier..."
My iOS version of the game uses 3rd party ads (Google) so I have to click yes, however tvOS doesnt have ads. 
Its a universal app tho, as in same project with 2 targets with 95% of the code being shared. The ad code is not shared and the frameworks relating to Google are only select to work with the iOS target (target membership)

Anyone who uploaded there app could maybe help me out please. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got my tvOS app approved. You have to select NO for using the advertising identifier. I guess it makes sense because my tv target does not use any ad frameworks or swift files. 
The way apple worded it on iTunes connect was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation with my App. One universal App with two targets (iOS + tvOS). The iOS version is using the Google Adsense SDK, therefore I selected yes for the "does your app use a advertising identifier..." question. I think that is correct, because there was no specific tvOS question,

Comment: lol, I selected no after thinking for ages. On mine all the ad frameworks and code only runs on the ios target so in theory the tvOS version should not have any ads. They didnt make that bit very clear, guess i find out soon.

Comment: see my answer above, you have to select no.